# Simple active directory permissions issue

Tags: active-directory, permissions, virtualbox

I've created a Domain Controller and 3 additional machines (`SQL-A`, `SQL-B`, `SQL-CORE`). All are on Windows Server2008R2 as VMs running on virtualbox. I have successfully joined the 3 machines to the domain.

Next, I created a user in Active Directory called `Kim_Akers` who is a member of `Domain Admins`, `Domain users`, `Enterprise Admins` and `Schema Admins`.

When I login to `SQL-A` (for example) as `[domain]\Kim_Akers` and then try and run something like `ServerManager.msc`. I get a permissions error:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions.

What am I doing wrong such that `Kim_Akers` doesn't have permissions to do this?

Comment: How long did you wait before testing "Kim_Akers"?

Comment: @boburob A few minutes, but I just restarted the machine, and it still has an issue.

Comment: Have you double checked that Domain Admins is in the local administrators group on the SQL servers?  Is this only happening on SQL-A, or on all 4 servers with that user?  What about a different user in the same groups?

Comment: @boburob  With only one Domain Controller in this domain, there should be 0 delay, since there's no inter-DC replication.

Comment: @SteveG Yes Domain Admins is in the local administrators group. The problem happens on all machines. I created another user name in the same groups and it shows the same behavior. I know I've probably done something stupid, but I'm at a loss as to why it won't work.

Comment: @HopelessN00b your right, sorry, I read 3 domain controllers and 1 test server...

Comment: A couple other troubleshooting steps I can think of:  Try adding Kim_Akers to the local admin group on the server and see if it fixes things.  Also, try turning UAC off on the machine temporarily and see if it gives the user access.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running servermanager.msc (or more specifically, MMC.EXE) as an Administrator (i.e.: right-click and "Run as administrator").  If not, UAC *may* be the cause, in that your full-admin token isn't being used to launch the .EXE

Comment: No I wasn't choosing "run as administrator", however when I try this I get the same error message as before. Note I'm not prompted for a login / password. Thanks anyway.